# django.core.exceptions.improperlyconfigured unknown parameters loader

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Good day everyone!
I'm tryna create affiliate marketing website, but have been having some errors lately this the kind of error i got when i run python manage.py runserver
django.core.exceptions.improperlyconfigured unknown parameters loader

Comment: Please add the full traceback for the error to the question

Comment: Please describe the error in brief in the question

Comment: The problem is with the template settings